# How to get text of td next to its previous sibling th with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup/Python, I like to get the `td` text, `Med` from the following screenshot, or the ETF Risk from [this website](https://www.zacks.com/funds/etf/VTI/profile?q=vti).

[image]

I tried the following code, but it didn't work.   What should be corrected?

```
Risk = soup.find('th', string="ETF Risk").find_sibling("td").text
```

Comment: please paste the html instead of a screenshot

Comment: `string="ETF Risk"` doesn't match because the `<th>` has two DIVs nested in it, and their text is part of the `<th>` text.

Comment: You could use a regular expression `^ETF Risk` to match anything that begins with that.

Comment: Can you post a small example code, how to use a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and `pseudo class` like `:-soup-contains()` to search by text values.

But why not using HTML structure here - There are id attributes available:

```
soup.select_one('#tooltip_etf_risk').parent.find_next_sibling('td').text
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<tr>
    <th class="alpha">ETF Risk 
        <div class="tooltip-wrapper"><button class="tt-trigger" aria-controls="tooltip_etf_risk" aria-expanded="false" tt-init="true"><span class="info-tooltip" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">More Info</span></button></div>
        <div class="tooltiptext hide" id="tooltip_etf_risk">
            <p>Zacks proprietary quantitative models divide each set of ETFs following a similar investment strategy (style box/industry/asset class) into three risk categories- High, Medium, and Low. The aim of our models is to select the best ETFs within each risk category, so that investors can pick an ETF that matches their particular risk preference in order to better achieve their investment goals.
            </p>
        </div>
    </th>
    <td><span class="rank_chip rankrect_3 rankchip_medium">Med</span></td>
</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('#tooltip_etf_risk').parent.find_next_sibling('td').text
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should use the method `find_next_sibling`, here is the workable one.

```
>>> soup.find('th').find_next_sibling('td').text
'\nMed == $0\n'
>>> soup.find('th').find_next_sibling('td').find('span').text
'Med'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  find_next_sibling didn't work either.  As Barmar commented, I need to figure out how to call that specific <th> of "ETF Risk" in its text.